# 127.0.0.1:8001 refused to connect when kubectl proxy to access kubernetes dashboard

Tags: neo4j, kubernetes, kubeadm

I deploy a cluster (neo4j) with kubeadm based on [this](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/kubernetes-neo4j) guide. Now I have these pods :

```
NAME           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
neo4j-core-0   1/1     Running   0          20h
neo4j-core-1   1/1     Running   0          20h
neo4j-core-2   1/1     Running   0          20h
```

and these services :

```
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP             60d
neo4j        ClusterIP   None             <none>        7474/TCP,6362/TCP   20h
nginx        ClusterIP   None             <none>        80/TCP              25h
```

Then I install kubernetes dashboard :

```
kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

So when I do `kubectl proxy` to access the dashboard, with below link, it says ***127.0.0.1 refused to connect***.

`http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/`.

What should I do to access the dashboard?

I also create sample user following [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user) guide.

Answer (score 13):

Kubernetes dashboard fully rely on Apiserver. `Connection refused` means there is an issue with communication with apiserver. Please see https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above#kubectl-proxy

Also you can try to run

```
kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --port=8002 --accept-hosts='.*'
```

And check if on other interface(port 8002) rather than `127.0.0.1` it works.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix, edit the kubernetes-dashboard yaml file >> selector type is "ClusterIP" to "NodePort" if you are running on localhost.
then visit "https://master_ip:exposed_port"

i think this helps.